# PowerQuery merge columns

Tags: excel, merge, powerquery

I have two tables. Table 1 and Table 2.
Table 1 = raw data
Table 2 = conditional filter to apply to Table 1

Goal: Each row in Table 2 will have 1 or more column data.  If the same column from Table 1 contains the filter item it the "Result" column wording will populate to a new Table 3.

Issue: The below code currently works only if Table 2 has all columns exactly matching

Question: Looking for coding recommendations/guidance on how to trigger the "Result" column to only be required for each row of columns populated in Table 2.  Would some kind of List.Contains() work where it ignores "null" columns?

Table 1 - raw data

[image]

Table 2 - filters for Table 1

[image]

Table 3 - results

[image]

Code I am currently using:

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Test", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"},Table2,{"Test", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4"},"Table2",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Table2", {"Result"}, {"Result"})
in
    #"Expanded Table2"
```

Comment: Still stuck on this problem. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab at this. But first, let me say that I'm thinking that your table 3 would not actually show green, because there would be no matches. Here's what I came up with...

I started with this as Table1:

[image]

...and this as Table 2:

[image]

Then I came up with this M code:

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Table1Listed", each Record.ToList(Table1{[Index]})),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Table2Listed", each Record.ToList(Table2{[Index]})),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Result", each if List.ContainsAny([Table1Listed],[Table2Listed]) then [Table2Listed]{List.Count([Table2Listed])-1} else null),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Test", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Result"})
in
    #"Removed Other Columns"
```

...to get this result:

[image]